# Reading XML to DataSet with multiple tables in file

Tags: c#, xml, winforms, xsd

I'm working on building an XML editor for a personal project. Using WinForms `DataGridView` control and `DataSet`, I was able to set up Read/Edit/Save with little issue, using a separate XML file for each type.

However, as I started to try adding more "advanced" controls, it became cumbersome to work with several different files - requiring `if` statements depending on which file I was working with. So, I tried combining these files into one larger file, as below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Items>
  <Armor>
    <Item>
      <Name>Test Armor</Name>
      <Value>1234567</Value>
      <Rarity>Common</Rarity>
      <Slot>Chest</Slot>
      <Damage>1234567</Damage>
      <Defense>1234567</Defense>
      <Health>1234567</Health>
      <Mana>1234567</Mana>
      <Strength>1234567</Strength>
      <Dexterity>1234567</Dexterity>
      <FlavorText>Something about stuff</FlavorText>
      <ImageSource>C:\Items\img.gif</ImageSource>
    </Item>
  </Armor>
  <Consumables>
    <Item>
      <Name>Test Potion</Name>
      <Value>1234567</Value>
      <Damage>1234567</Damage>
      <Defense>1234567</Defense>
      <Health>0.1234567</Health>
      <Mana>0.1234567</Mana>
      <Strength>1234567</Strength>
      <Dexterity>1234567</Dexterity>
      <FlavorText>Something about stuff</FlavorText>
      <ImageSource>C:\Items\img.gif</ImageSource>
    </Item>
  </Consumables>
  <Junk>
    <Item>
      <Name>Test Junk</Name>
      <Value>1234567</Value>
      <Stackable>Yes</Stackable>
      <FlavorText>Something about stuff</FlavorText>
      <ImageSource>C:\Items\img.gif</ImageSource>
    </Item>
  </Junk>
  <QuestItems>
    <Item>
      <Name>Test Quest Item</Name>
      <Stackable>Yes</Stackable>
      <FlavorText>Something about stuff</FlavorText>
      <ImageSource>C:\Items\img.gif</ImageSource>
    </Item>
  </QuestItems>
  <Weapons>
    <Item>
      <Name>Test Weapon</Name>
      <Value>1234567</Value>
      <Rarity>Common</Rarity>
      <Slot>Primary</Slot>
      <Damage>1234567</Damage>
      <Defense>1234567</Defense>
      <Health>1234567</Health>
      <Mana>1234567</Mana>
      <Strength>1234567</Strength>
      <Dexterity>1234567</Dexterity>
      <FlavorText>Something about stuff</FlavorText>
      <ImageSource>C:\Items\img.gif</ImageSource>
    </Item>    
  </Weapons>
</Items>
```

And the schema, generated from Visual Studio's `Create Schema` menu, and minimally modified - such as changing `unsignedInt` to `int`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="Items">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="Armor">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:element name="Item" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                <xs:complexType>
                  <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element name="Name" type="xs:string" />
                    <xs:element name="Value" type="xs:int" />
                    <xs:element name="Rarity" type="xs:string" />
                    <xs:element name="Slot" type="xs:string" />
                    <xs:element name="Damage" type="xs:int" />
                    <xs:element name="Defense" type="xs:int" />
                    <xs:element name="Health" type="xs:int" />
                    <xs:element name="Mana" type="xs:int" />
                    <xs:element name="Strength" type="xs:int" />
                    <xs:element name="Dexterity" type="xs:int" />
                    <xs:element name="FlavorText" type="xs:string" />
                    <xs:element name="ImageSource" type="xs:string" />
                  </xs:sequence>
                </xs:complexType>
              </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
        <xs:element name="Consumables">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:element name="Item" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                <xs:complexType>
                  <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element name="Name" type="xs:string" />
                    <xs:element name="Value" type="xs:int" />
                    <xs:element name="Damage" type="xs:int" />
                    <xs:element name="Defense" type="xs:int" />
                    <xs:element name="Health" type="xs:decimal" />
                    <xs:element name="Mana" type="xs:decimal" />
                    <xs:element name="Strength" type="xs:int" />
                    <xs:element name="Dexterity" type="xs:int" />
                    <xs:element name="FlavorText" type="xs:string" />
                    <xs:element name="ImageSource" type="xs:string" />
                  </xs:sequence>
                </xs:complexType>
              </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
        <xs:element name="Junk">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:element name="Item" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                <xs:complexType>
                  <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element name="Name" type="xs:string" />
                    <xs:element name="Value" type="xs:int" />
                    <xs:element name="Stackable" type="xs:string" />
                    <xs:element name="FlavorText" type="xs:string" />
                    <xs:element name="ImageSource" type="xs:string" />
                  </xs:sequence>
                </xs:complexType>
              </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
        <xs:element name="QuestItems">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:element name="Item" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                <xs:complexType>
                  <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element name="Name" type="xs:string" />
                    <xs:element name="Stackable" type="xs:string" />
                    <xs:element name="FlavorText" type="xs:string" />
                    <xs:element name="ImageSource" type="xs:string" />
                  </xs:sequence>
                </xs:complexType>
              </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
        <xs:element name="Weapons">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:element name="Item" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                <xs:complexType>
                  <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element name="Name" type="xs:string" />
                    <xs:element name="Value" type="xs:int" />
                    <xs:element name="Rarity" type="xs:string" />
                    <xs:element name="Slot" type="xs:string" />
                    <xs:element name="Damage" type="xs:int" />
                    <xs:element name="Defense" type="xs:int" />
                    <xs:element name="Health" type="xs:int" />
                    <xs:element name="Mana" type="xs:int" />
                    <xs:element name="Strength" type="xs:int" />
                    <xs:element name="Dexterity" type="xs:int" />
                    <xs:element name="FlavorText" type="xs:string" />
                    <xs:element name="ImageSource" type="xs:string" />
                  </xs:sequence>
                </xs:complexType>
              </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Both of these files are wholly representative of their counterparts - I had separate files for `Armor`, `Consumables`, etc.

The expected outcome was to have one file representing the previously separate files, such that:

`Items` is the `root` node. 
Within `Items` are the parent nodes - `Armor`, `Consumables`, etc. 
Within each parent node are the child nodes `Item` and their properties.

As far as I can tell, the XML structure and schema looks correct, but when I try to read this file into my program, I receive the error: `System.FormatException - "Input string was not in a correct format."`.

The stack trace shows that `System.Number.StringToNumber` is throwing this exception. I've dug through the file and the schema a few times and can't seem to find where this is occuring, and the exception detail doesn't provide much further detail.

In my code, I'm reading the data simply using

```
DataSet data = new DataSet();            

data.ReadXmlSchema(itemSchema);
data.ReadXml(itemData);
```

This exact method worked without issue when the files/schema were separate, which further leads me to believe I've simply overlooked something in the XML/Schema.

At this point, I'm stuck and not sure what it could be. I would greatly appreciate if anyone can help me solve this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you repeat the element `Item` on each item type.
When your code reads the schema, it finds the first appearance of the `Item` element and tries to apply the same schema to every other appearance; so, when it reads the `Test Potion` it tries to read it as `string`, `int`, `string`, `string`, `int`, `int`, `int`, `int`, `int`, `int`, `string`, `string` and fails when it finds the 0.1234567 `Health` value.

My suggestion would be to change your schema it to something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Items>
  <Armor>
    <ArmorItem>
    ...Item elements
    </ArmorItem>
  </Armor>
  <Consumables>
    <ConsumableItem>
    ...Item elements
    </ConsumableItem>
  </Consumables>
  <Junk>
    <JunkItem>
    ...Item elements
    </JunkItem>
  </Junk>
  <QuestItems>
    <QuestItem>
    ...Item elements
    </QuestItem>
  </QuestItems>
  <Weapons>
    <WeaponItem>
    ...Item elements
    </WeaponItem>    
  </Weapons>
</Items>
```

Comment: That actually makes really good sense! I didn't think of that.

Comment: aaand it worked perfectly. Thanks for pointing this out. Learned something new!